# Difference between defaultselenium.shutdownseleniumserver and seleniumserver.stop

Tags: selenium

1) What is the difference between defaultSelenium.shutDownSeleniumServer() and seleniumServer.stop() ?
I observe that when I just use

```
defaultSelenium.stop();
seleniumServer.stop();
```

the browser closes but the server does not shut down. If that is the case, what is the use of seleniumServer.stop()?

2) Is this the right sequence of commands? If not, what is and why?

```
defaultSelenium.stop();
defaultSelenium.shutDownSeleniumServer();
seleniumServer.stop();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to this question can be found on [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/selenium-users/R60bBcA1puA/k80eTSe8EgsJ).